# grouping objects with modifiers so it behaves like one object

Tags: modeling, animation, weight-painting, groups

Grouping objects with modifiers so it behaves like one object.

Is it possible to make a such grouping?
I made shoes for a character that I want to animate.
The shoes are composed of several elements (sole, body, tongue, laces, etc) with various modifiers on each.

I already know that I will have to modify/adjust the model once I start to animate the feet, so I would like to keep it editable as much as possible.

Is there an easy way to make a such grouping that I didn't find yet?
Or, do I have to go through a trick, like create an empty in the middle of the shoe, parent all the elements to that and so on? but then, I am not sure if the weight painting will work.

what's the easiest solution?

thanks

Comment: Yes, parent to an empty or parent to the main part of the shoe... why wouldn't weight painting work?

Comment: so far, when I try that: every pieces of the shoes get separated when I move my skeleton

Comment: it's probably because you need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode. Actually if your shoe is parented to a bone you don't even need to find a way to join the objects together, the fact that they are parented to the bone should work

Comment: ok, but then is there an easy way to not end up like this: (see attached pic, flying laces)
https://i.imgur.com/fEPKTqT.jpeg

Comment: the way is a correct weight painting   ;)   it's often necessary to rework after you've parent with automatic weight, with the brush in weight paint mode or with the vertex group list and the Assign or Remove button

Comment: OK I found a technique that work well so far: I use 'surface deform modifier' and bind the elements of the shoe's main body. It stick miraculously. It's even possible to use several surface deformers at the same time. Only the main body is attached to the skeleton / has weight paint. I suspect 'mesh deform' should be use in some other situations

Comment: yes mesh deform is great when you have cloths, it prevents any exagarate mesh twisting, in your case I thought you could fix it with weight paint only

Comment: @moonboots tell me, now that I render my animation, it's like the surface deform modifier had never existed. Preview window = the laces stick to the shoe, rendered video the laces stay in the air without moving an inch. Do you have an idea why? (I did activate the effect for rendering -camera icon- )

Comment: maybe share your file (only keep the important part)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots after further trials, it seems that when I put the effect on the top of the modifier stack it gets back to normal. Not sure why, not sure if my modeling will look exactly the same